# Activité de trancher la reliure d'un livre ?

Tags: japonais, demande-de-mot

Comment désigne-t-on l'activité de trancher la reliure d'un livre ?

(Ça permet ensuite de scanner chaque page du livre. Le mot en japonais est [断裁](http://www.kinkos.co.jp/news/cutting.html).)

Le mieux que j'ai trouvé pour l'instant est « tranchage », mais apparemment utilisé dans des contextes beaucoup plus divers :

[https://www.google.com/search?q=断裁&tbm=isch](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E6%96%AD%E8%A3%81&tbm=isch)
https://www.google.com/search?q=tranchage&tbm=isch

En fait, je cherche un magasin qui offre ce service, mais je ne sais pas quel mot entrer sur Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je te propose le mot « massicoter » ou « massicotage ».

> *Massicoter* désigne l'action de couper de façon perpendiculaire un matériaux se présentant sous forme de feuilles.

Ce terme n'est pas spécifique au domaine de la reliure (on peut couper des feuilles de métal avec un massicot) mais il est largement utilisé dans le domaine de l'imprimerie.

Je pense que cela te permettra de trouver le service souhaité via Google.

Answer (score 3):

**Massicoter**, Le massicotage d'un livre peut permettre sa numérisation automatique.

Plusieurs réponses sur les moteurs de recherche